# Define a type if does not exist

Tags: c++, c++11, types

What I am looking for seems to be basic but I have no idea about checking types without producing error.

How can I check if type `uint` does not exist then define it as `unsigned int`?

Comment: This is something you know beforehand, ie., if its built-in data type then you include the type definition otherwise compiler will complain expectedly. Although you can do this for macros obviously

Comment: @PnotNP, I will not write a library which fails on the other computers and OS, then ask users to fix it by themselves?

Comment: No, you don't do anything, thats what compilers are for. Compiler will fail automatically if the definition doesnt exist on other computers. You can use standard library definition from `<cstdint>` or you can define your own header with macros

Comment: @PnotNP, does any macro tell you `uint` does exist?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you would put it in your own namespace.
You can `using` that namespace, if there is a collision the user can
specify with the scope operator (`::`). Often, library vendors
let user have the option to not `using` the namespace with a macro.
(Or more commonly the reverse)

Checking if `uint` already exist, and conditionally define it if
it does not, can only be done if you can be sure it is defined
as a macro, something that rarely holds in c++

If it is a fundamental type, you can use for example `std::uint32_t`
from `<cstdint>`.